# Glitch noise with AudioKit

Tags: swift, audiokit

I've released iPhone app which uses AKOscillator to ring the sounds. There are some glitch noises.

I'm afraid that it may be troubelesome for you to download and try it, but I want to know the noises due to my code or AudioKit itself.

Here's a link of my app.
Of course, it is free.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kist/id1320616182?mt=8

And I put related code I wrote below.

```
    //connect nodes
    oscillator1 = AKOscillator(waveform: AKTable(.triangle))
    oscillator2 = AKOscillator(waveform: AKTable(.sine))
    panner1 = AKPanner(oscillator1, pan: -1)
    panner2 = AKPanner(oscillator2, pan: 1)
    mixer = AKMixer(panner1,panner2)

    //Generate FreqArray
    for i in 0...360 {

          let freq = (220 * pow(2, i / 120))
          freqArray.append(freq)
    }


    //The function to ring the sounds  
    func letSoundOut(_ toPoint:CGPoint) {

          let x = round(toPoint.x)
          let y = round(toPoint.y)

          if (y < 0 || y > 360) || (x < 0 || x > 360) {

              mixer.stop()
          }
          else {

              mixer.start()
              oscillator1.frequency = freqArray[Int(y)]
              oscillator2.frequency = freqArray[Int(x)]
          }
     }
```

The value of x and y is limited between 0 and 360, because the size of the drawing canvas is 360pt x 360pt.

I use AudioKit 4.0.4, swift 4, Xcode 9.2

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to update AudioKit to the develop branch.  Or change the triangle to a different waveform because that is the culprit.  We will create an AudioKit 4.0.5 branch with the fix built in. Sorry for the problem.

Comment: Hi, Aure, thank you for your reply! I'll wait for 4.0.5. Anyway, I definitely love AudioKit!